# Search a Value from Table in Angular

Tags: angular, html

In App.Component.ts, I have a object note like this.

```
handler(value: any) {    
    for (let j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
      var note = new Notes(value[j].Id,
                           value[j].Subject, 
                           value[j].NoteId, 
                           value[j].Type, 
                           value[j].Description,
                           value[j].SendToGIS,
                           value[j].AddedBy,
                           value[j].AddedOn
                          );  
        this.tripNotes.push(note);  
    };     
  }
```

I want to search for particular description. Through a search box. How can I access note in App.component.html.

```
<tr *ngFor="let note of tripNotes ;  let i = index "  
    (click)="getDetailedNotes(i);setClickedRow(i);" 
    [class.active]="i==selectedRow" >
  <td>{{note.Type}}</td>
  <td>{{note.Subject}}</td>
  <td>{{note.Description}}</td>
  <td>{{note.SendToGIS}}</td>
  <td>{{note.AddedBy}}</td>
  <td>{{note.AddedOn}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` function to search through the array.

Firstly, you'll want to create a new variable for the filtered array

```
this.filteredNotes = this.tripNotes;
```

Then, use the `filter` function:

```
this.filtetedNotes = this.tripNotes.filter((note) => note.Description.indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1)
```

And in the HTML, make sure you're pointing at the `filteredNotes`

```
<tr *ngFor="let note of filteredNotes;  let i = index "  
    (click)="getDetailedNotes(i);setClickedRow(i);"
    [class.active]="i==selectedRow" >
```

Answer (score 0):

When `searchKey` updated in search field, update `filtetedNotes` using `filter` function. Initially assign `tripNotes` to `filtetedNotes`. Use `filter()` as below :

```
myFunction(){
    this.filtetedNotes = this.tripNotes.filter(note=> {
        let filterText = this.searchKey.toLocaleLowerCase();

        //Full Description search (from start)
        if (note.Description.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterText)) {
            return note;
        }

        //Full Description search (anywhere in the Description)
        if (note.Description.toLowerCase().contains(filterText)) {
            return note;
        }

        //Partially Description search (from start)
        let parts = note.Description.split(' ');
        if (parts) {
            if (parts.some(x => x.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterText))) {
                return note;
            }
        }

        return null;
    });
}

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchKey" (ngModelChange)="myFunction()" placeholder="Enter some text to search">
//input field in App.Component.html
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I call this from App.component.html. This is the search box from which i need to search : <input type="text" placeholder="Enter some text to search">. And this is the table row from where i need to seach. <tr *ngFor="let note of tripNotes ;  let i = index "  (click)="getDetailedNotes(i);setClickedRow(i);" [class.active]="i==selectedRow" >
      <td>{{note.Type}}</td>
      <td>{{note.Subject}}</td>
      <td>{{note.Description}}</td>
      <td>{{note.SendToGIS}}</td>
      <td>{{note.AddedBy}}</td>
      <td>{{note.AddedOn}}</td>
    </tr>

Comment: Code edited. Try this. Hope it will work fine.And yes, choose only one from these three.
`1. Full Description search (from start)`
`2. Full Description search (anywhere in the Description)`
`3. Partially Description search (from start)`

Comment: [(ngModel)]="searchKey" (ngModelChange)="myFunction()". they are not supporting. Instead of these I am using ng-model="searchKey" ng-change="myFunction()"

Comment: Also I don't need to add any pipes here: <tr *ngFor="let note of tripNotes ;  let i = index "  (click)="getDetailedNotes(i);setClickedRow(i);" [class.active]="i==selectedRow" >
      <td>{{note.Type}}</td>
      <td>{{note.Subject}}</td>
      <td>{{note.Description}}</td>
      <td>{{note.SendToGIS}}</td>
      <td>{{note.AddedBy}}</td>
      <td>{{note.AddedOn}}</td>
    </tr>

Comment: There are no pipe at all

Comment: Currently there are no pipe. Is it required. ?

Comment: Nope.Its not required